# Angular da error al recibir un status 400 al consumir api

Tags: angular

Estoy consumiendo un api con angular la cual retorna estdos 404, 400 o 200 pero cuando recibo un estado que no es el 200 por ejemplo el 400 o 404 angular da exception con el siguiente error.

La api retorna un json la cual dice que atributos debo ingresar junto al código 400 pero angular me salta a una exception.

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/users/add", ok: false, …}
error:
usapellidos: "Ingrese los apellidos"
usnombres: "Ingrese el nombre"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: () => {…}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure response for http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/users/add: 400 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/users/add"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
constructor: class HttpErrorResponse
__proto__: Object
```

Controlador de angular.

```
addUsuario(usuario: CUsuarioVO) {
    usuario.estado = "1";
    //  if (usuario.nombres != "" && usuario.apellidos != "" && usuario.telefono != "" && usuario.correo && usuario.IdArea > 0 && usuario.Idrol > 0 && usuario.clave != "") {
    this.servicioUsuario.agregarUsuario(usuario).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('Aca no llega con el error 400');
      if (data.message) {
        if (data.message == "Agregado") {
          this.mensajesInputs(data);
          this.ngOnInit();
        } else {
          this.alertsMessage(data.message, false);
        }
      } else {
        this.mensajesInputs(data);
      }
    });
    // } else {
    // this.alertsMessage("Campos incompletos", false);
    // }
  }


// Este es el servicio que esta en otra clase angular


agregarUsuario(usuario: CUsuarioVO) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/add`, usuario, { responseType: 'json' });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que se muestre un error en la consola es normal ya que no se está manejeando el error en ninguna parte. Para evitar eso podrías configurar un manejador de errores global: [Error Handler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler).

Para reaccionar cuando la petición falle se puede usar una sobrecarga del método `subscribe()` que recibe un objeto con las propiedades: `next` que contiene la función a ejecutar en caso de éxito y `error` que se ejecutará en caso de error.

```
this.servicioUsuario.agregarUsuario(usuario)
    .subscribe({
       next: (data: any) => {},
       error: (response : any) => {
        console.log(response.error);
       }
    });
```

Comment: el unico inconveniente es que en el error: () etc... al no existir data no puedo obtener el json que esta en data : any

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.